# How to connect jsp to cassandra 1.0.8?

Tags: cassandra

I have planned to do project using jsp and cassandra i need to know what are the steps to be followed to set up a connection between jsp and cassandra? example connection code in jsp will really help. Thnak you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official Cassandra Java option [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions)

In JSP you can embed java code using scriptlets.